# Rcpp: cannot open shared object file

Tags: rcpp, arrayfire

I'm trying to develop an R package, which makes use of [Arrayfire](https://github.com/arrayfire/arrayfire), thanks to Rcpp library.
I've started writing a sample code (let's name it **hello_world.cpp**) which looks like this:

```
#include <arrayfire.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
bool test_array_fire(){
    af::randu(1, 4);    
    return true;
}
```

Then, I tried to compile it using a `sourceCpp` function

```
Rcpp::sourceCpp('src/hello_world.cpp')
```

My first suprise was the fact I had to set some flags manually (`sourceCpp` seems to ignore **Makevars** config when compiling a piece of C++ code). 
I did it with:

```
Sys.setenv("PKG_CXXFLAGS"="-std=c++11")
Sys.setenv("PKG_CPPFLAGS"="-I/opt/arrayfire/include/")
Sys.setenv("PKG_LIBS"="-L/opt/arrayfire/lib64/ -laf")
```

However, the code still does not compile properly. Each trial finishes with the following output:

```
Error in 'dyn.load("/tmp/RtmpHaODIU/sourceCpp-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-1.0.2/sourcecpp_689c5adb8d/sourceCpp_14.so")':
unable to load shared object '/tmp/RtmpHaODIU/sourceCpp-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-1.0.2/sourcecpp_689c5adb8d/sourceCpp_14.so':
  libaf.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Unfortunately, I could not find an solution for my problem (even if some Stack Overflow questions raise issues which are more or less similar at first glance).

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 8):

The error occurs very late in the process when R tries to load the shared object file. This means that compilation and linking worked fine with the help of the environment variables you set. But in the final step the *run-time linker* does not know where `libaf.so.3` is located. This is a configuration one normally does at the OS level, e.g. on my system

```
ralf@barra:~$ /sbin/ldconfig -p | grep libaf
        libafopencl.so.3 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/libafopencl.so.3
        libafopencl.so (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/libafopencl.so
        libafcpu.so.3 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/libafcpu.so.3
        libafcpu.so (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/libafcpu.so
        libaf.so.3 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/libaf.so.3
        libaf.so (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/libaf.so
```

And if I try your example it works without problems with a shared object file that is linked against `libaf`:

```
ralf@barra:~$ ldd /tmp/RtmpcjY9dN/sourceCpp-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-1.0.2/sourcecpp_13d33790279c/sourceCpp_7.so | grep libaf
        libaf.so.3 => /lib/libaf.so.3 (0x00007f21037ed000)
```

I expect that in your case the first command will provide no result and the second (adjusted) command will lead a "file not found"(?) error.

There are several ways to tell the run-time linker about the location of the library:

- Edit `/etc/ld.so.conf` or (better) place a file in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/`, c.f. http://arrayfire.org/docs/installing.htm#Linux.
- Set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.
- Add `-Wl,-rpath,/opt/arrayfire/lib64/` to `PKG_LIBS`
- Install ArrayFire into a directory that the linker searches by default. That's what I am doing since I compile from source and use the [resulting DEB packages](https://github.com/arrayfire/arrayfire/wiki/Build-Instructions-for-Linux#packaging).

As for `Rcpp::sourceCpp` not respecting a `Makevars` file: The problem is that the C++ file you write cannot be used directly. Instead Rcpp attributes has to create additional wrapper functions, which is done in a temporary directory. Now one could in principle copy a `Makevars` file into that directory as well. However, one normally sets such variables with the help of `Rcpp::plugins` and `Rcpp::depends` attributes. For example, switching on C++11 is done using `// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp11)]]`. For the other variables, you could write your own plugin or us the one provided by my [RcppArrayFire](https://www.daqana.org/rcpparrayfire/).

However, I suggest you start with a package if that is your goal. `Rcpp::sourceCpp` is great for many things, but interfacing with a system installed library without the help of an R package is not one of them.

Comment: Ok. My intention was to treat this simple example with `sourceCpp` as a warm-up before package developing.

Comment: @KrzJoa One can use `sourceCpp` that way. Did the configuration change for the run-time linker work? Concerning existing packages: arrayfire-r makes a large subset of the API available at R level, but it is not complete. RcppArrayFire does not try to make the API available at R level. Instead it makes it easy to go to C++ where of course the full API is available. This is similar to packages like PcppArmadillo, Rcppeigen and RcppGSL.

Answer (score 3):

A few things, quickly:

- when you use `sourceCpp()` you are not using a package
- randomly dropping variable used with a package do not help
- there actually *is* a package by Ralf whi will probably chime in
- and we have a writeup about it [here at the Rcpp Gallery](https://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/introducing-rcpparrayfire/)

So I would probably start by redoing / rebuilding the examples from the Rcpp Gallery [article about RcppArrayFire](https://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/introducing-rcpparrayfire/).

Comment: So, to sum up:
1) `sourceCpp` does not use Makevars and we have to set the flags with `Sys.setenv`
2) You encourage to use RcppArrayFire instead of linking C++ ArrayFire lib on one's own. 
By the way, I know RcppArrayFire package and I saw the article in the Rcpp Gallery. However, I was trying to compose Rcpp with C++ ArrayFire lib in more "straightforward" way (i.e. without using any additional Rcpp wrappers). I was just trying to learn Rcpp by  finding more universal solution, which facilitates to add an arbitrary C++ library (not only the ones already wrapped with Rcpp).

Comment: @KrzJoa I am curious what you would see as more "straightforward". If you have any suggestions please don't hesitate to [file an issue](https://github.com/daqana/rcpparrayfire/issues). BTW, are you familiar with https://github.com/arrayfire/arrayfire-r?

Comment: @KrzJoa: Even as a _non-package alternative for simpler tasks_, `sourceCpp` does reflect environment variables.  Please the [Rcpp Attributes](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-attributes.pdf) vignette for more on it.  And also see dozens of other answers here by me and others saying :use a package" when faced with a more involved task, ie one involving system libraries.  As Ralf just said again as well.

Comment: Yes, I know both *RcppArrayFire* and *arrayfire-r*. However, I'm still not sure if they offer access to **full** ArrayFire API. That is the reason I decided to start with bare-metal C++ library instead of using some convenient () wrappers.